# Why does this PhaseRange not work?

Tags: plotting, functions, options, signal-processing, control-systems

Any idea why this PhaseRange does not work?

```
BodePlot[-(1/(s + 1000)), PlotLayout -> "Phase", 
 PhaseRange -> {0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

[image]

Comment: The values on the y-axis on the left are in degree, while the PhaseRange option is specified in radians. So only if the phase would exceed -360 in your plot, the PhaseRange option would take effect.

Comment: @Mathias `PhaseRange -> {-180, 180}` doesn't work either. Why does it need the phase exceeding -360 for the option to be effective? I don't quite get it.

Comment: What if I want the phase to start at 180 degree instead? What setting should I use?

Comment: A canonical sample of a **"minimal working example"**.

Comment: @Syed what do you mean?

Comment: I mean it is very good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug and is fixed in v13.1 to give the following correct results.

```
BodePlot[-(1/(s + 1000)), PlotLayout -> "Phase", "PhaseRange" -> #, 
   PlotLabel -> Switch[#, Automatic, #, _, Row[{#, " i.e. ", N[#/Degree]}]] ] & /@ 
      {Automatic, {-π, π}, {0, 2 π}, {2 π, 4 π}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Everything is working correctly. Mathematica is showing a correct Bode plot, the frequency range is just automatically set to display interesting (attenuating, likely to contain gain & phase margins) part.

First of all, for your filter, the minus sign reverses the phase ($-\pi$) and shifts backwards. So the range of phase shift starts from $-\pi$ until, as this is a decay transfer, $-\pi-\pi/2$. The interesting part happens at about $1000\;\mathrm{Hz}$, at its decay rate, as shown in your plot. To have wider frequency range,

```
BodePlot[TransferFunctionModel[-1/(s + 1000), s], {10^-1, 10^8}, PlotLayout -> "Phase", PhaseRange -> {0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Let's say it is required to show this plot from -180 to -225 degrees., How could it be done?

Comment: @Syed `PlotRange -> {-180,-225}`

Comment: What's the purpose of `PhaseRange` then? Note that the option can be removed altogether and the result does not change. May be the reason for having it in the first place is hiding in the docs somewhere.

Comment: @Syed `PhaseRange` is just the phase range of the input of the linear transfer function (filter)... The whole point of Bode plot is to see how the filter transfers the phase (and gain) of the input, which always requires at least one cycle ($2\pi$) or its multiple ($2\pi n$) to study its proper behavior.

Comment: @ShinKim can you plot it with phase starting from 180 degree instead (phase range from 180 to 0 degree)?

Comment: @Syed `PhaseRange`  only works if the phase range exceeds 360 degree. However, what if you want to plot the function with phase range from 180 to 0 degree? I don't see any way to do that from BodePlot. You can use the defintion `ArcTan` but that is not what I want here. If you plot this function with  `ArcTan`   you would get phase from 180 to 0 degree.

Comment: @hana I think you have a misunderstanding of what filters or Bode plots mean. You cannot draw Bode plot from 180 to 0 degrees, Bode plot is always representing $2\pi n$ because linear transfer function is obtained from Laplace transform, whose domain $s$ is complex number with $\arg s=\omega n=2\pi f n$, a multiple of frequency, a multiple of cycle.

Comment: @ShinKim as an EE I don't think I misunderstood it. I want it like this but use BodePlot. Of course they're same if you add or subtract any interger number  of 360 degree.

Comment: @ShinKim ```makePhasePlot[expr_, s_Symbol, {fmin_, fmax_}] := 
 Module[{ex, f, re, im, data}, ex = expr /. s -> (2 Pi f I);
  re = ComplexExpand[Re[ex]];
  im = ComplexExpand[Im[ex]];
  data = Table[{Log[10, f], 180/Pi ArcTan[re, im]}, {f, fmin, fmax, 
     0.1}];
  ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
   ImageSize -> 300, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"angle(deg)", None}, {"Frequency (rad/sec)", 
      None}}, Axes -> False, GridLines -> Automatic]]
makePhasePlot[-1/(s + 1000), s, {1, 10000}]```

Comment: @hana Then just specify the input phase to `PhaseRange -> {2*Pi, 4*Pi}`...

Comment: @ShinKim `PhaseRange -> {2*Pi, 4*Pi}` doesn't work. If it works on your PC, could you put it in your answer?

Comment: @hana Could you provide the full line of your `BodePlot` beforehand?

Comment: @hana, it works on my PC. I am using 12.2.0Win7-x64. [graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwHzz.png)

Comment: @Syed Mine is 12.1.1.0 and it doesn't work. Probably I should update.

Comment: @hana`BodePlot` last updated in V10, so I suspect your code has an error, which for some reason you're not providing.

Comment: @ShinKim oops, you're right. It works now but why `{2*Pi, 4*Pi}`? I don't get it. The phase of this function is from 180 to 0 so why not  `{0, 2*Pi}`

Comment: @ShinKim can you explain this?

Comment: @Syed can you explain this?

Comment: Your TF starts at -180 due to a negative sign and loses another 90 for the only pole encountered. In Mathematica, try: `Mod[#, 360] & /@ {-180, -270}`. This is what you are seeing. This is similar to Matlab's [unwrap](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unwrap.html).

Comment: @Syed I meant why it is `{2*Pi, 4*Pi}` not `{0, 2*Pi}`.

Comment: I think you have to keep adding/subtracting $2\pi$ till it is in the range $0$-$2\pi$. While specifying `PhaseRange` it has to be a multiple of $2\pi$ between min and max values, so that leaves us with $4\pi$ for the max value.

Comment: @hana As Syed said as well as my answer in the very beginning, the phase input `{0, 2*Pi}` has the phase shift ranging from $-180^\circ$ to $-270^\circ$. If you want the phase shift ranging from $180^\circ$ to $90^\circ$ in the Bode plot (i.e., shifted $+2\pi$), then you have to shift the input phase with the same amount $+2\pi$, leaving `{2*Pi, 4*Pi}`.

Comment: @Syed I was thinking that `{0, 2*Pi}` is the result not the number to add. The documentation is not clear that part.

Comment: @ShinKim to be honest I don't see anything new in your answer. What I was confused is why `{0, 2*Pi}` does not work and you didn't explain it and also didn't explain why `{2*Pi, 4*Pi}`.

Comment: @hana Your question did not ask that, but that the Bode plot is simply 'not work'. And through your comments I came to realize that your understanding on the subject matter is simply insufficient, which is the root of your question. Then kindly updated the answer explaining what `PhaseRange` means and why the $y$-axis ranges from $-180^\circ$ to $-270^\circ$, which you still fail to grasp.

Comment: @I asked in the comment and Syed finally explained it. Your answer mentioned nothing about that.

Comment: @hana To be fair though, Syed answer isn't correct, which you should know better. And if you read/understood the second paragraph of my answer, you'd know that that basically explains why it has to be `{2*Pi, 4*Pi}` for the Bode plot to be ranging $180^\circ$~$90^\circ$.

Comment: @ShinKim I don't see anything new in your second paragraph. I know that the minus sign means 180 degree lag and one pole delay 90 degree at frequency > 10 pole frequency. Did you mention anything relate to `{2*Pi, 4*Pi}` there? I don't think so. I don't have any problem understanding bode plot as I did it a lot for many years as an EE. Your post basically explain the bode plot not PhaseRange of the function BodePlot.

Comment: @hana I'm sorry, but what are you even talking about? What do you mean by degree *lag* and *pole*? Please read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) community guideline; flagging to close the thread.

Comment: @ShinKim I'm not going to explain the pole and phase lagging as it is not related to Mathematica.  Maybe you could google it to read more about it. No problem close it as I'm done now.

Comment: @ShinKim anyways, thanks for the help that `{2*Pi, 4*Pi}` in the comment does work though it is not mentioned in your answer.